# search for pattern and insert text that precedes the pattern from pattern1 to pattern2 exclusive

Tags: search, command-line, replace

basically I have a bunch of lines of code that all match the format `.\module.variable (),
.\module.variable2 (),`

I want to take everything between the backslash and the space, before the parentheses and put it in the parentheses for each line, with whatever is on that line, like this: 
`.\module.variable (module.variable),
.\module.variable2 (module.variable2),`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visit each line that has the key pattern using the [`g`lobal command](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#:g) and do a (global) [substitution](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#:s) on that same pattern at each visited line:

```
:g/\.\\\(\S\+\) ()/ s//.\\\1 (\1)/g
```

The pattern, which is used in both the global and substitution operations:

- `\.\\` : period and backslash
- `\(\S\+\)` : non-empty, non-space string inside a capturing group (`\(...\)`) which allows us to reference the match in the replacement section of the substitution operation
- `()` : a space and empty pair of parens

We leave the pattern in the substitution operation empty which indicates that we want the last used pattern. The replacement part then just uses the [capturing group back reference](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#s/%5c1) (`\1`) twice to build the target string. (Note: I don't think Vim help refers to these constructs as "capture/capturing groups" but it's pretty much a universally used term for them.)

Comment: Couldnt you do this with `%s/the messy pattern/the repl/g` ? Why invoke `global`?

Comment: Of course you can but there's no significant upside to doing so and its not very interesting (everyone knows plain `:s`) while mine is more likely to expand a newer user's skill set (without being an unrealistic approach) and that possibility is one of the main reasons I do this. If I were teaching a bunch of professionals who planned to use this on huge amounts of text I'd probably have done differently but that's not what's going on here.

Comment: Plus there are already so many posts here that are just glorified regex questions and the banner says Vi/Vim. Plus...well you get the point.

Comment: What would you have said to a bunch of professionals using this on huge amounts of text?

Comment: "Use sed". But seriously if someone insisted on using vim/ex to do big batches of find/replace I'd tell them to use whatever I found to be the fastest performer based on some relevant benchmarking/testing.

Comment: The major advantage I'm finding with the use `:g` is to first test that the pattern I'm using touches the lines I wish and not others.  (Yes, `:s/<re>/<rpl>/c` also accomplishes this).  I'm discovering though that visualizing what will be touched before touching it has it's benefits.